# Using CSS, how do you create a text stroke outline that is *thicker* than 1px?

Tags: css, stroke, outline

Below is the code I was using to do a Text Stroke outline of 1px. But how do I get the outline thicker? If I just replace all "1px" with "5px", the result looks crazy.

HTML

```
<div class="element">
Hello!
</div>
```

CSS

```
.element {
color:white;

    text-shadow:
        -1px -1px 0 #000,
        1px -1px 0 #000,
        -1px 1px 0 #000,
        1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```

Comment: That’s because text shadows are not outlines; they’re shadows. You can’t simply replace shadow positions and expect a thicker “outline”.

Comment: 5px --> you mean probable 0.5px ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Why `0.5px`? The OP needs a thicker outline, not a thinner one.

Comment: @Xufox I don't know, but my mind read it thinnner :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `SVG` as well, though it requires more code:

```css
.element {
  font-size: 50px;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.3em;
}

svg text {
  fill: pink;
  stroke-width: 8px;
  paint-order: stroke;
  stroke: violet;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <svg><text x="8px" y="75%">Hello kitty!</text></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can consider `text-stroke` but you need to pay attention [to browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=text-stroke)

```css
.element {
  color: white;
  font-size:50px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 5px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  Hello!
</div>
```

Comment: Interestingly, this css property has been in webkit for more than a decade, but it's still not part of the official css spec.

Comment: Didn't know this property. It would be very useful in mobile dev.