# How to add stroke for html styling in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, stroke

I have a lock-screen widget that uses a .js file to do the styling of a clock element. The problem is that depending on the wallpaper, that clock's color is hard to read sometimes (black on dark background). I found the element that changes the clock text's color but that's not enough. I want to be able to add a stroke to it so that it has a thickness and dual colors. That way it will be clear to read whatever the background.

The actual element is this:

```
var elements = {
    "zclock": {
        "z-index": 2,
        "color": "gray",    <--- This changes color of clock text
        "webkit-text-stroke-width": "3px",
        "font-family": "sanfranlight",
        "position": "absolute",
        "font-size": "51px",
        "top": 0,
        "left": 1,
        "width": "119px",
        "text-align": "right",
        "font-weight": "100"
    },
    <omitted rest>
    };
```

I've tried using something called `-webkit-text-stroke-width` but that didn't work. Maybe I entered it wrong because it's only ever referenced in css files in online examples.

I want to get this kind of effect (or similar)
[image]

This is for an iPhone/iOS so it would be whatever webkit Safari uses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using CSS, how do you create a text stroke outline that is \*thicker\* than 1px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51459653/using-css-how-do-you-create-a-text-stroke-outline-that-is-thicker-than-1px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hellow,

you can try to add a "-webkit-text-stroke-color" property to this object too and may increase the "font-weight". The "webkit-text-stroke-width" property in your code may needs also a leading "-" to work.

[Example in pure CSS / HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/SamBrishes/btcp2j7k/)

```
.element{
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 51px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 3px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}
```

See also [-webkit-text-stroke-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke-width) and [-webkit-text-stroke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke) on MDN.

Sincerely,
Sam.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using IE 11 and the `-webkit-text-stroke` is not working as it is not supported: [see here](https://caniuse.com/#search=text-stroke)

What you can try using instead is `text-shadow`. [See supported browsers here](https://caniuse.com/#search=text-shadow)

It is really nicely explained [here](https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/)